# Splunk monitor does not show entire file but only shows the first line

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am monitoring a file from linux host but splunk is showing only the first line. I want to display the entire file content. I will be running a script which will generate a file with multiple line everytime and I want to stream the entire file to splunk. The below is my config, am I missing something?

```
splunk:
            monitors:
              - index: "test-index"
                file: "/path/my-data-*"
                sourcetype: "testsource-{{profile.pipelineBuildNumber}}"
                multiline_event_extra_waittime: "true"
```

Comment: What query are you using to view the contents of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added config to inputs.conf and props.conf, restarted splunk and it worked as expected.

input.conf

```
[monitor:///file*]
index = test-index
sourcetype = test-sourcetype
```

props.conf

```
[test-sourcetype]
DATETIME_CONFIG=CURRENT
HEADER_FIELD_LINE_NUMBER=1
FIELD_DELIMITER=,
FIELD_QUOTE="
ENDOFFILE
```